# Como calcular média entre linhas

Tags: r

Tenho um conjunto de dados de informações com anos nas linhas. Preciso fazer uma média de dois em dois anos, como o exemplo abaixo, em que as 4 primeiras colunas são os dados existentes e as duas últimas, o que se deseja calcular. Tentei com `aggregate` e `apply`, mas não tive sucesso.

Meus dados estão a seguir:

```
structure(list(
  Cod_ARES = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
  ano = c(2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020), 
  AG001 = c(1, 2, 4, 1, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 2, 5), 
  AG002 = c(3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3), 
  AG001M = c(NA, 1.5, 3, 2.5, 3, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 2.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5), 
  AG002M = c(NA, 2.5, 2, 3, 4.5, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1.5, 2.5)), 
row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse é um problema de média móvel. O objetivo é calcular a média aritmética dos últimos dois períodos. O pacote `zoo` do R é capaz de realizar essa tarefa facilmente com a função `rollmean`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric

dados <- dados[, 1:4]

dados %>%
  mutate(AG001M = rollmean(AG001, k = 2, fill = NA, align = "right"),
         AG002M = rollmean(AG002, k = 2, fill = NA, align = "right"))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 6
#>    Cod_ARES   ano AG001 AG002 AG001M AG002M
#>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1        1  2015     1     3   NA     NA  
#>  2        1  2016     2     2    1.5    2.5
#>  3        1  2017     4     2    3      2  
#>  4        1  2018     1     4    2.5    3  
#>  5        1  2019     5     5    3      4.5
#>  6        1  2020     4     1    4.5    3  
#>  7        4  2015     4     5    4      3  
#>  8        4  2016     3     1    3.5    3  
#>  9        4  2017     2     1    2.5    1  
#> 10        4  2018     5     1    3.5    1  
#> 11        4  2019     2     2    3.5    1.5
#> 12        4  2020     5     3    3.5    2.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Perceba o que fiz acima:

- carreguei os pacotes necessários para a análise;
- selecionei apenas as 4 primeiras colunas do conjunto de dados fornecido;
- com a função `mutate`, criei novamente as colunas `AG001M` e `AG002M`, que são as médias móveis de dois períodos para as variáveis `AG001` e `AG002` respectivamente. Os argumentos da função `rollmean` são, na ordem,

  - o número de períodos (`k = 2`);
  - o preenchimento de médias que não podem ser calculadas com `NA` (`fill = NA`);
  - o deslocamento das médias calculadas para a última linha do data frame (`align = right`);

Comment: Marcus, deu super certo! Não conhecia o pacote zoo. Muito obrigado! Parabéns pela dedicação aos que estão aprendendo...

Comment: Obrigado! É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.